# Use a string as a Uri

Tags: c#

After choosing a photo from the gallery of the device, I saved the path of this photo, so I can reuse it at a later app's startup. The problem is that I can't use that string as a Uri, but when I convert it adds a file:/// before.

Here is the code:

```
MessageBox.Show(imgdefault); // Print C:\Data\Users\Public\....\photoname.jpg
Uri imageUri = new Uri(imgdefault, UriKind.Absolute); //I try to trasform the string to Uri
MessageBox.Show(imageUri.ToString()); // Print file:///C:/Data/Users/Public/..../photoname.jpg
BitmapImage imageBitmap = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
sagoma.Source = imageBitmap; // obviously doesn't find the image
```

How i can convert the string in Uri so i can use that image in device in the application (in few words without the file:/// before the path?)

---

Update:

Now i try to change my code like that:

```
    MessageBox.Show(imgdefault); // Print C:\Data\Users\Public\....\photoname.jpg
MessageBox.Show(File.Exists(imgdefault).ToString()); // Print false
    BitmapImage imageBitmap = new BitmapImage();
    imageBitmap.UriSource = new Uri(imgdefault, UriKind.Absolute);
    MessageBox.Show(imageBitmap.UriSource.IsFile.ToString()); // Print true
    sagoma.Source = imageBitmap;
```

So from the second message box there is no file in that path (and so no image?) but when we arrive to the third messagebox there is a file on it.
But if it is a wrong path, why told me that is the path when i take the image from gallery?

Comment: That is a totally fine file path.

Comment: are you having issues or are you confused by the tripple forward slashes when you're use to seeing single `'\` back slashes

Comment: I can't understand you, can you explain me please?

Comment: The file path is just a UNC file path, not a Windows file path.

Comment: And so i can't use it?

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine and should work.

Comment: But it doesn't. When i restart application don't take the image but with the messagebox (the one in the question) print the correct path. Can i miss some permission somewhere?

Comment: I just tried it and it works.

Comment: Nothing don't work at me. I select a photo and save the path string. I restart application, give me the correct path but don't show the photo on it. Do you have any idea why doesn't work for me?

Comment: Not at the moment. We need to get some things clear. How do you determine that `imageBitmap` doesn't contain the image?

Comment: When i launch the application on device for debugging should appear the photo on the page but there isn't nothing. Now I insert after the imageBitmap creation a MessageBox.Show(imageBitmap.UriSource.IsFile.ToString()) and return true. So in imageBitmap there is the file selected. But why I can't view on the page so?

Comment: What device are you talking about?

Comment: Nokia Lumia 520, the one with i do test

Comment: No one can help me more?